# Something strange happens in bash when I add to large numbers

Tags: bash, algebra

I encounter something strange when I execute a summary of integers in bash. Why is that?

```
$ echo $(( 27989065672496370937 + 1 ))
-8904422474922732294
```

I mean, it looks like a ring or something like that. But then I'd expect something like 18.446.744.073.709.551.616 and -18.446.744.073.709.551.616

Comment: From quick tests, it does appear that bash works with 64 bit integers (and does some strange stuff with signed/unsigned conversions). I did not find documentation for this though.

Comment: I think this is the extent of the documentation: in [Shell Arithmetic](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Arithmetic): "Evaluation is done in fixed-width integers with no check for overflow"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's 64-bit *signed* integers. This is the largest positive number:

```sh
$ echo $((2 ** 63 - 1))
9223372036854775807
```

When you add one to that:

```sh
$ echo $((2 ** 63))
-9223372036854775808
```

For arbitrary-width numbers, you'll need an external tool, like `bc`

```sh
$ bc <<< "27989065672496370937 + 1"
27989065672496370938
```